# Find a sequence of real sequences which converges in one space but not in another (related space)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I'm having trouble coming up with a solution to this problem and if you could help me by finding such a sequence to satisfy the below and could explain your method of doing so, it would help a lot.

We have that for all $q \in [1,\infty]$ we construct the metric space:

$$\mathcal{G}^q = \{a \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} | \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} | a(k)|^{q} \lt \infty \}$$

with the distance $d_q$:

$$d_q(x,y) = \|x-y\|_{q} = \sqrt[q]{\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}|x(k) - y(k)|^q }$$

We must find $L \in (\mathcal{G}^{3})^{\mathbb{N}}$ which converges in $\mathcal{G}^{4}$ but not in $\mathcal{G}^{3}$.

Thanks for your help,
Helen.

Comment: A few typesetting and notation notes, for norms it should be typed `\|x-y\|` instead of `||x-y||`.  Compare $\|x-y\|$ to $||x-y||$.  Second, I've never heard this space being called $\mathcal{G}^q$ before, I've generally seen it called $\ell_p$.  As for the content of your question, do you know of any divergent series in the usual sense?  (i.e. divergent in $\ell_1$ or $\mathcal{G}^1$?)  Try to modify one of those accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the $n$-th term of $L$ the sequence whose first $n$ terms are $\left(\frac1n\right)^{1/3}$ and whose remaining terms are all $0$. The only possible limit is the all-zero sequence, but each term of $L$ is at distance $1$ from it in $\mathcal{G}^3$. In $\mathcal{G}^4$, however, the distance from the $n$-th sequence to the all-zero sequence is

$$\left(n\left(\frac1n\right)^{4/3}\right)^{1/4}=\frac{n^{1/4}}{n^{1/3}}=\frac1{n^{1/12}}\;.$$

There are two ideas in play here. One is to use sequences that are eventually $0$ if possible, since they’re especially easy to work with. The other is that for positive reals less than $1$, cube roots are bigger than fourth roots. If I can find a sequence of sequences whose norms in $\mathcal{G}^3$ just barely fail to converge to $0$, in $\mathcal{G}^4$ they’ve a good chance of doing so.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer. Is it possible that you could also explain the metric space in question here as I'm having trouble understanding what it means? Thanks!

Comment: @Helen: Can you pinpoint where you’re having trouble? The points of $\mathcal{G}^3$ are the sequences $x=\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of real numbers such that $\sum_{k\in\Bbb N}|x_k|^3$ is finite. The distance from $x$ to the zero sequence is $\left(\sum_{k\in\Bbb N}|x_k|^3\right)^{1/3}$. The distance between sequences $x$ and $y$ is the distance from the sequence $x-y$ to the zero sequence, where the sequence $x-y$ is defined termwise, just like the difference of two vectors in some $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Just in general for the $\mathcal{G}^{q}$.So, is this the set of real sequences such that the sum of each sequence with its terms raised to $q$ is finite?

Comment: @Helen: The sum of $q$-th powers of the absolute values of the terms, yes.

Comment: Thanks for your help Brian, I think I understand how this construction of metric spaces works now :)

Comment: @Helen: Excellent! You’re welcome.